# How to generate log files larger than 500m

Tags: awk

I need to make a minor change in an `awk` portion of a shell script to only generate log files larger than 500m…

Keep in mind that this script run on Sun, AIX, HP-UX and various flavors of Unix and Windows.

Here is the script:

```
# command for gathering Listener Log
set v_listener_command "
echo '            Listener Log' | tr '\\n' ':'; echo '' | tr '\\n' ' '
lsnrctl status | grep Log | awk '{ print \$4 }' | sed 's/alert\\/log.xml/trace\\/listener.log/g' | tr '\\n' ' '
echo '-' | tr '\\n' ' ' ; du -sk `lsnrctl status | grep Log | awk '{ print \$4 }' | sed 's/alert\\/log.xml/trace\\/listener.log/g'` | awk '{if ( \$1 / 1024 + 0.5 >= 500 ) print $1 }' | tr '\\n' ' '
echo '(Mb)'
```

### Error:

```
can't read "1": no such variable while executing
"set v_listener_command "
echo '            Listener Log' | tr '\\n' ':'
echo '' | tr '\\n' ' ' 
lsnrctl status | grep Log | awk '{ print \$4 }' | s..."
(file "/CTM/ctmuser/scripts/GetDBLog/exec_sshlogin_don.exp" line 101)]
```

Comment: Is your first command really `set v_listener_command "`? With the dangling `"`?

Comment: why do you tag with `awk` if this is an `expect` script?

Comment: @terdon...yes thats the first command we can get rid of the dangling .".

Comment: @roaima ...sorry its and expect script that part of a shell script

Comment: You can [edit] your own question, you know. To fix the typo(s) and to clarify points of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

That's very painful.

- Use a function. Don't try to stuff code into a variable. I'm assuming you're using a POSIX-type shell (sh, bash, ksh, ...) but I might be wrong.
- Capture the information you need, and use `printf` instead of all those `echo | tr` sequences

This can be simplified further still.

```
v_listener_command() {
    log=$( lsnrctl status | awk '/Log/ {print $4}' | sed 's,alert/log.xml,trace/listener.log,g' )
    size=$( du -sk "$log" | awk '$1 / 1024 + 0.5 >= 500 {print $1}' )
    printf '            Listener Log: %s - %s (Mb)\n' "$log" "$size"
}
```

---

Oh, I see that this is an expect script.

```
proc v_listener_command {} {
    set log [exec lsnrctl status | awk {/Log/ {print $4}}] 
    set log [string map {alert/log.xml trace/listener.log} $log]

    set size [exec du -sk $log | awk {$1 / 1024 + 0.5 >= 500 {print $1}}]

    puts [format "            Listener Log: %s - %s (Mb)\n" $log $size]
}
```

Comment: @gleen Jackman... Thanks for your response.... this is an expect script and it runs against 28 different servers scanning both listener and alert log files (with different paths.) My question again is this, will it be possible to just modify this portion of the script [awk {$1 / 1024 + 0.5 >= 500 {print $1}}] by declaring the variable '1' because i keep getting the same error [can't read "1": no such variable].

Comment: it's a quoting problem: you have onion-like layers of code, and getting the quotes and backslashes right is increasingly difficult. That's why I demonstrate splitting the problem into smaller parts that are easier to handle. You don't need to create one massive command and execute it all at once.

Comment: I do appreciate what you are saying in terms of breaking down the code. The problem is that the expect code is part of a shell script that runs against several servers (varying os from unix to windows). I am new to expect and i am just trying to simply this code to  generate the desired output.